# Java EE container authentication on Jboss using Spring Security

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, authentication, jboss, spring-security

I'm trying to implement client authentication on Jboss EAP 6.2 with Spring Security in order to protect my REST api (with no login page), but I've stucked.

Trying to send authentication request with ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : '/client-web/j_security_check',
    data : {
        j_username : user,
        j_password : pass
    }
}).done(function(data) {
    $('div#result').append($('div').text('Login ' + user + ' OK'));
}).fail(function(data) {
    console.log(data) 
    $('div#result').append($('div').text('Login ' + user + ' FAIL'));
});
```

I received '404 Not Found' as response. I've also tried to access j_spring_security_check but result was the same. 
Sending request to one of my */rest/* methods always returned '403 Forbidden', even if I sent username and password fields in ajax request or provided `"Authorization" : "Basic *XXXX*"` header.

So now I cannot realize what should I do to authenticate my user against my application and how to check the authentication on subsequent requests.

I'm new to Spring Security and security at all as well as Java EE technologies and  a spent two whole days trying make it work but with no luck. So that's why I'm here asking you guys for help. I would appreciate any useful advice or the link to appropriate resources.

Here are the contents of my configuration files which I messed with:

**root-context.xml**:

```
    <http entry-point-ref="preAuthEntryPoint"
        authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager" auto-config="false"
        realm="ApplicationRealm">
        <intercept-url pattern="/rest/**" access="ROLE_CUSTOMER" />

        <!-- <form-login /> -->
        <http-basic />
        <logout />
        <jee mappable-roles="customer" />
    </http>

    <beans:bean name="preAuthEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint">
    </beans:bean>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"
        id="authenticationManager">
        <sec:authentication-provider
            ref="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider" />
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider"
        id="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:property name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService">
            <beans:bean
                class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedGrantedAuthoritiesUserDetailsService">
            </beans:bean>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
```

**web.xml**:

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>clientServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/clientServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>clientServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/resources/home.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>All Content</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>ROLE_CUSTOMER</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>ROLE_CUSTOMER</role-name>
    </security-role>
```

**jboss-web.xml** has only one node: `<security-domain>mySecurity</security-domain>`

And in the jboss **standalone.xml** config file there is a `<security-domain>`:

```
<security-domain name="mySecurity" cache-type="default">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DatabaseServerLoginModule" flag="required">
            <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/myDs"/>
            <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="select u.password from users u where u.username=?"/>
            <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="select r.name as rolename, 'Roles' as rolegroup from users u inner join users_roles ur on (ur.users_id = u.id) inner join roles r on (ur.roles_id = r.id) where u.username=?"/>
        </login-module>
    </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

Comment: I suggest you use a REST client to troubleshoot what is happening. You can try "POSTMAN Rest Client" from Chrome Store. `404 Not Found` means that you are not properly hitting the required URL. If I do not recall wrongly, you need  `j_spring_security_check` rather than `j_security_check `

Comment: Thanks for your advice Mario. I'll try this Postman app and then put the results here if any.

Comment: Try adding the following to the logging configuration in the standlalone XML file you are using:    <logger category="org.jboss.security">  
     <level name="TRACE" />  
   </logger>  
   <logger category="org.jboss.web.tomcat.security">  
     <level name="TRACE" />  
   </logger>  
   <logger category="org.apache.catalina">  
     <level name="TRACE" />  
   </logger>

Comment: apologies for the formatting there!